# Spring Client Needs to Retrieve Connection from Pool if the connection has been closed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, connection-pooling

So my company is relatively new to Spring. This will be our first production implementation of the framework, and as such, we're having some of the usual pains of moving to a new method of doing things.

Anyway, this new application is a replacement for our old password manager, so it needs to be accessible via client at basically any time. The issue we're having is that our front-end connection gets abandoned because of no activity for too long, as we'd like it to. The trouble comes in when we want to get the connection back, say when a user returns to their workstation in the morning. I've looked around for days and can't seem to find anything helpful, but maybe it's easier to fix than it seems.

Database config:

```
    private String _getConnectionUrl() {
    /* mysql connections on tomcat crash overnight.
     * Probably need to investigate autoreconnect 
     * https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
     */
    return String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:3306/%s",_dbHost,_dbSchema);
}


/**
 * gets the datasource associated with this connection
 * @return
 */
public DataSource getDataSource() {

    if(_dataSource==null) {
        _log.info(String.format("Creating DataSource to %s",_getConnectionUrl()));

         PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
          p.setUrl(_getConnectionUrl());
          p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          p.setUsername(_dbUsername);
          p.setPassword(_dbPassword);
          p.setJmxEnabled(true);
          p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
          p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
          p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
          p.setTestOnReturn(false);
          p.setValidationInterval(30000);
          p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
          p.setMaxActive(100);
          p.setInitialSize(10);
          p.setMaxWait(10000);
          p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
          p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
          p.setMinIdle(10);
          p.setLogAbandoned(true);
          p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
          p.setJdbcInterceptors(
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;" +
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer");
        _dataSource = new DataSource();
        _dataSource.setPoolProperties(p);
    }

    return _dataSource;

}
```

We are using a hibernate as the JPA engine, and MySQL5 as the database.

I can provide more code upon request.

Stack trace for error after connection has been abandoned:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:117) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer.invoke(ResetAbandonedTimer.java:60) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:152) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:40) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.swecunet.portal.PortalJPADatabase.save(PortalJPADatabase.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
at org.swecunet.portal.pwmgr.PWMController.passwordGet(PWMController.java:152) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:128) ~[spring-security-kerberos-web-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Edit - 
Persistence settings defined in our JPA connection class:

```
    private EntityManager _entityManager;
/**
 * gets the JPA entity manager associated with this database connection
 * @return
 */
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if(_entityManager==null) {
        _entityManager=getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }
    return _entityManager;

}

/**
 * Save an entity into this database
 * @param entityObjectToSave the @Entity jpa object within the model package namespace
 */
public void save(Object entityObjectToSave) {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    getEntityManager().persist(entityObjectToSave);
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();       
}

/**
 * Delete an entity from this database
 * @param entityObjectToDelete the @Entity jpa object within the model package namespace
 */
public void remove(Object entityObjectToDelete) {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    getEntityManager().remove(entityObjectToDelete);
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();       
}

private EntityManagerFactory _entityManagerFactory; 

public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    if(_entityManagerFactory==null) {

        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        emf.setPersistenceUnitName(_dbSchema);
        _log.info(String.format("Scanning %s for entity models...", _dbJPAPackageLocation));
        emf.setPackagesToScan(_dbJPAPackageLocation);    
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hjpa=new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hjpa.setShowSql(_dbJPAShowSQL);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hjpa);
        Properties properties = new Properties();           
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        emf.setJpaProperties(properties);           
        emf.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        emf.afterPropertiesSet();
        _entityManagerFactory=emf.getObject();
    }
    return _entityManagerFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has a bug with maintaining a connection for a long period, that C3P0 fixes.

Try adding these to your persistence.xml

```
      <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
      value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="60" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull"></property>
```

Comment: We're actually not using Persistence.xml, we're defining everything in Java classes which create beans. Persistence configurations have been added to OP.

Comment: It could still be that Hibernate is timing out, and you still need c3p0 as a dependency to maintain the connection for you.